# Who are the people from the random images when the SO has been temporarily down?

Tags: discussion

Recently, while looking for the questions I noticed that the SO site was temporarily down. Then I refresh it for 10-20 times. Every time I refresh it new images has been shown. Who are they? Are they employees of SO?

[image]

If they are employees of SO, does SO also train cows to do programming works? :) Just kidding.

[image]

Comment: For a cow, that is ugly enough to resemble a horse!

Comment: Oh no! It's not a cow, nor a horse. It's a unicorn!

Comment: Try out your [facial recognition skills](http://stackexchange.com/about). The one in the top right is Joel Spolsky. The one three down on the left is Marc Gravell.

Comment: Yep, employees of StackOverflow! Some tongue-in-cheek fun, is all. or a bribe to calm us down while SO is hiding

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203635

Comment: what kind of laptop are they using? looks like military grade laptop

Comment: @od3n: Looks like vtech to me ;)

Comment: @animuson According to the link by Martin Smith, that's not Joel Spolsky, it's Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe. :P

Comment: @od3n It is a V-Tech Talking Whiz Kid Mouse PRO Deluxe. Source: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/workin-on-ur-problemz/

Comment: @Alexis Ha, guess it's more obvious with a larger image.

Comment: Where can I get one of those unicorn masks?

Comment: I want to know what laptop they are using? I know it's probably a child's toy but still...